# Error in Zeppelin configuration to access cluster from non cluster node

Tags: apache-zookeeper, apache-zeppelin, apache-phoenix

I have a 4 nodes cluster setup using ambari , now I need to setup a zeppelin .  Due to some reason I need to setup zeppelin on node which is not part of cluster but that will be part of same subnet where cluster is running, i.e I need to access the cluster from zeppelin which is installed on another node .

I Installed zeppelin and configured new interpreter **phoenix**  as per in the given  [link](https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/56113/trying-to-create-phoenix-interpreter-using-jdbc-in.html) , since this zeppelin node is not part of cluster I modified the default.url like below

default.url jdbc:phoenix:10.189.8.78:2181:/hbase-unsecure

my  zk quorum is running on 10.189.8.78:2181 so I gave this .

after configuring I tried to execute the simple query

%pheonix

DROP VIEW IF EXISTS "test_table"

but getting the below error

```
org.apache.phoenix.exception.PhoenixIOException: Failed after attempts=35, 
exceptions:
Fri Oct 13 06:50:38 UTC 2017, RpcRetryingCaller{globalStartTime=1507877420557, pause=100, retries=35}, org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MasterNotRunningException: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MasterNotRunningException: Can't get connection to ZooKeeper: KeeperErrorCode = ConnectionLoss for /hbase-unsecure
```

Comment: Hi, I don't know about ambari well. But here is one thing you can check: **is it possible to run phoenix client (CLI) on the machine where Zeppelin is installed?** If this is possible, it's the Zeppelin issue. Otherwise, it probably be network issue.

Comment: try dropping the /hbase-unsecure from the jdbc url